# How to hide a badge when the value is empty or zero

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I would like my PrimeFaces [`p:badge`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/badge.xhtml) not to be visible when the value is zero or empty.
The following will display a badge with the value `0`:

```html
<p:badge value="0">
  <p:avatar label="Badge"/>
</p:badge>
```

And if I use an empty value an empty badge will be displayed:

```html
<p:badge value="">
  <p:avatar label="Badge"/>
</p:badge>
```

Using the `rendered` attribute is no option as it will also hide the contents of the badge (the `p:avatar` in this case):

```html
<p:badge rendered="#{bean.value ne '0'}">
  <p:avatar label="Badge"/>
</p:badge>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### PrimeFaces 10

Have a look at the HTML that is rendered when an empty value is used:

```html
<div id="..." class="ui-overlay-badge">
  <span class="ui-badge ui-widget"></span>
  ...
</div>
```

You can simply hide empty elements using the `:empty` CSS selector. So you can hide empty badges using CSS like:

```css
.ui-badge:empty { display: none; }
```

This CSS rule requires you to have an empty value in order to hide the badge.
If you want to hide the badge if the value is `0`, you could use a ternary expression to map `0` to empty:

```html
<p:badge value="#{bean.value eq '0' ? '' : bean.value}">
  <p:avatar label="Badge"/>
</p:badge>
```

See also

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

### PrimeFaces 11+

In PrimeFaces 11 the `visible` attribute is [introduced](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/7677). It can be used like:

```html
<p:badge value="#{bean.value}" visible="#{not empty bean.value}">
  <p:avatar label="Badge"/>
</p:badge>
```

or

```html
<p:badge value="#{bean.value}" visible="#{bean.value ne '0'}">
  <p:avatar label="Badge"/>
</p:badge>
```